# android standalone app from ejected expo project only shows blank screen

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have an issue in using ejected expo project.
I have created an expo project and eject it.
It works well on both ios and android before publish, that is, works well on local.

After publishing, ios standalone app is works well, but android stand alone app shows only blank(white) screen and doesn't show any other screens.

Below is my app.json file.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "neighborhood",
    "description": "This project is really great.",
    "slug": "neighborhood",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "30.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./src/assets/images/icon.png",
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./src/assets/images/notification_icon.png",
      "color": "#000000"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "........",
      "publishBundlePath": "ios/neighborhood/Supporting/shell-app.bundle",
      "publishManifestPath": "ios/neighborhood/Supporting/shell-app-manifest.json"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "............",
      "publishBundlePath": "android/app/src/main/assets/shell-app.bundle",
      "publishManifestPath": "android/app/src/main/assets/shell-app-manifest.json"
    },
    "isDetached": true,
    "detach": {
      "iosExpoViewUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/exp-exponent-view-code/ios-v2.8.4-sdk30.0.0-3de13133-1adc-4ba1-8569-a84011e570b4.tar.gz",
      "androidExpoViewUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/exp-exponent-view-code/android-v2.8.1-sdk30.0.0-271c32ab-0715-4dfb-8270-ecead3679bb4.tar.gz"
    },
    "scheme": "expe0dee74a172e495fbe7bdc05832274ac"
  }
}
```

Bellow is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "empty-project-template",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "emoticons-converter": "^1.0.3",
    "expo": "^30.0.1",
    "expokit": "^1.7.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-autolink": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.2.8",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-phone-call": "^1.0.9",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.0",
    "runes": "^0.4.3"
  }
}
```

As before I said ios standalone app works well, but the android standalone app shows blank screen.

PS: App.js file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Navigator, BackHandler, Alert, SQLite } from 'react-native';

import {SafeAreaView, createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

import SignIn from './src/pages/SignIn';
import CreateProfile from './src/pages/CreateProfile';
import Home from './src/pages/Home';
import CreateNotification from './src/pages/CreateNotification';
... ... ...

const Navigation = createStackNavigator(
    {
        SignIn: {screen: SignIn},
        CreateProfile: {screen: CreateProfile}, 
        Home: {screen: Home},
        ... ... ...
    }
)


export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

   render() {
        return(
            <Navigation
            />
        )
    }
};
```

PS: SignIn.js

```
export default class SignIn extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    };
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isSplashScreen: true,
        };
    }
    ... ... ...
    async componentWillMount() {
        setTimeout(async() => {
            this.setState({isSplashScreen: false});
        }, 3000);
    }
    render() {
        if(this.state.isSplashScreen) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.containerSplash}>
                ... ... ...
                </View>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                ... ... ... 
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have splash screen on your project?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have use splash screen but not use default splash screen. I will upload my navigation file(App.js). In that file I use custom splashscreen.

Comment: What is the way of your using splashscreen? Does it work if you remove your splashscreen?

Comment: In SignIn.js file, first,  this.state.isSplashScreen = true. so when load this js file then shows splash screen view(styles.containerSplash). But after 3s, this.state.isSplashScreen = false. So shows main SignIn screen view(styles.container)